# Recursion using the stack memory in C

Tags: c, stack-memory

I've read about how the stack looks.
I understood that the parameters for the function will be pushed first, than the return address and finally the local variables of the function.

Is it possible to make a recursive function using the stack?

This is what I tried to do:

```
void f() {
    int x = 2;
    printf("hey\n");
    void (*p)() = (void (*)()) ((&x) - sizeof(x));
    p();
}
```

Comment: Not in a way that doesn't entail undefined behavior.

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do... don't.

Comment: Call m crazy, but if I wanted to recurse into `f()` from `f()`, I invoke `f()`. It's a world gone mad, right?

Comment: You have read *examples* of how a stack might be used. There are no guarantees that this is exactly (or even close) to how it actually works on some random C compiler. So, No.

Comment: `[teach-me]` You're making a number of wrong assumptions on how code and data are stored in memory. Please learn about stack, heap, code and data segments. Just because code and local variables are mixed up in the C code they do not end up in close memory locations.

Comment: @Arkadiy 
What are my wrong assumptions? And where can I read more about it?

Comment: Google "code segment". As for wrong assumptions, you're assuming that because `int f() {` and `int x = 2;` are next to each other in the program's text, they are next to each other in memory when the compiled code executes. Nothing can be farther from truth in C.

Comment: @Arkadiy
From what I understood about virtual memory, the program will treat them as they are next to each other in the memory although in fact the are not.

Comment: As I said, you have a number of wrong assumptions. Your understanding of virtual memory is another one. Please start reading things like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment

Answer (score 1):

`int func (int x)
{return (func(x-1);}` 
This is your recursive function using stack.

1. Everything is on stack (or maybe in registers) unless you allocate memory.

The function above doesn't allocate any memory (and will definitely cause stack overflow).

2. Your line 4 is something more than just UB, it is nonsence. You substract some bytes from pointer to X and think, that there may be a function. It will definitely cause segfault.

Comment: Yes I am aware of the stack overflow my program will cause, and I do not want to make recursion by calling the function again.
I wanted to somehow use the way the memory is stored in the stack and by accessing different adress, calling the function again.

Comment: @Ilay It sounds like what you really want is just a loop.

Comment: @dbush
We can call it a loop or a recursion it doesn't really matter. All I wanted is to check my understanding of the way the stack looks like and I guess something there is wrong.